# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION after mesh update

Tags: python, scripting

I have latest Blender v2.76b x64. I have a edited PSKX importer, the 2.69MB pskx file import working, but when i try a 2.82MB pskx file or 2.79MB pskx file, Blender crash on:

```
me_ob = bpy.data.meshes.new(objName)
#... adding vertices, meshes etc.
me_ob.update() #Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, line 760
```

Sample files with code: https://marekkraus.sk/BlenderScript.zip